# fish shell's string split and foreign languages

Tags: string, shell, utf, fish

quick question about fish's built-in `string` function, particularly `string split`. Does its implementation regard UTF of any size? And, if it does, does its implementation know how to handle UTF-32?

As an example, I wrote a simple function that reads from stdin and breaks the string down into an array.

```
function traverse
  set --local text (string split '' (read))
  echo $text
end

traverse
```

I then call this function in the script. I used the command `echo "test" | fish traverse.fish` which output `t e s t`, so that's good.

`echo "test 漢字" | fish traverse.fish` outputs `t e s t   漢 字`, so that works.

This next case is pecular.

`echo "test 漢字 الْحُرُوف الْعَرَبِيَّة" | fish traverse.fish` outputs `t e s t   漢 字   ا ل ْ ح ُ ر ُ و ف   ا ل ْ ع َ ر َ ب ِ ي َ ّ ة`. Now, I don't know arabic, but is this correct? It seems like the arabic characters may be UTF-32, and conjunctions of sorts can occur with simpler characters, but that's just a guess. My gut says this isn't how arabic should be split.

Knowing the details of `string split` regarding UTF would help I think, assuming that this indeed is an error of sorts.

EDIT: a better way to word my question would be: Does fish's `string split` function split between all graphemes defined by UTF, or just UFT-8/UTF-16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string split` operates on sequences of `wchar_t`. In Unix/Linux with typical usage, the input is converted to UTF-32 via the user's locale (using `mbrtowc`) and the splitting occurs via literal code point searching.

In the case of `string split ''` fish will convert the input to UTF-32, split by code point, and output each code point separately, converted to the user's locale. Decomposed characters and other grapheme clusters may be split.

Shells aren't well suited for Unicode-savvy text processing.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. So, a multitude of code point elements of the sequence can compose an Arabic character it seems, but all of the composing code points are also valid Unicode characters themselves?

Comment: There's two aspects here. One is the "accent" floating dots (ḍamma, fatḥah). These are represented with Unicode combining marks: they are separate code points, but are rendered as modifying another character. fish will split these.

The other is ligatures: this is a property of the font (so outside the scope of Unicode) that in this case makes the text look more "cursive."

In principle fish should not split characters from their combining marks, but this is a tall ask of a command line shell. Unicode-aware text processing should use a more dedicated tool.